# Detect whether Google User has logged in before

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm currently implementing the possibility for the user to login with Google.

**How can I detect whether this exact Google User has previously logged in to fetch data from the database.** So far, when a user has already logged in the past, logging in with Google overwrites the entry in the database.

Is there a way to check whether the auth id has already been setup before?

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    FirebaseApp.configure()

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

    Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true

    ...

    return true
}

// MARK: - Google SignIn
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {
    if let error = error {
        print("Failed logging into Google: ", error)
        return
    }

    print("Successfully logged into Google.")

    guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
    let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                   accessToken: authentication.accessToken)

    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (acc, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Failed to create User with Google: ", error)
            return
        }

        self.upDataToDatabase(from: user)

        print("Successfully created user with Google.")
    }
}

func upDataToDatabase(from user: GIDGoogleUser) {
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    let databaseRefUser = Database.database().reference().child("users/\(uid)")

    let userObject = [
        "name": String(user.profile.name),
        "email": String(user.profile.email),
        ] as [String: Any]

    databaseRefUser.setValue(userObject) { (error, ref) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Error creating Database connection: ", error as Any)
            return
        } else {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homeView") as! HomeViewController
            self.window?.rootViewController = controller
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
}

@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any])
    -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                                 sourceApplication:options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                                 annotation: [:])
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                             sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                             annotation: annotation)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase userId always remains same for a user until deleted.

```
 guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
 let databaseRefUser = Database.database().reference().child("users/\(uid)")
```

Check if databaseRefUser already exists than don't update the DB else setValue for the same.